# How to Insert Row Without Auto incrementing a ID Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a forced auto increment column. but some time i have to insert the value explicitly. For this purpose i set identity to on but it's not workin

Here is the code:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [menu_code] on

INSERT INTO [dbo].[menu_code]
VALUES('', '', '', '', '',
       1  -- Auto Generated Identity column
        ,'', '')
```

Comment: **HOW** is it *not working* ? Do you get errors? If so: **WHAT** errors? Are you just not getting any data in your table?

Comment: An explicit value for the identity column in table 'dbo.menu_code' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Comment: i thik this error should be occured because i set insert identity to on

Comment: but i am direcly inserting like this set identity_insert menu_code On insert into DM.dbo.menu_code select * from DM_LUBRICANTS.dbo.menu_code

Answer (score 3):

The error message is crystal clear on the cause of the problem:

> *An explicit value for the identity column in table 'dbo.menu_code' can only be specified **when a column list is used** and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON*

You need to **explicitly define** what the columns are that you're trying to insert values into!

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [menu_code] ON

INSERT INTO [dbo].[menu_code] (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, IdentityCol, Col6, Col7)
VALUES('', '', '', '', '',
       1  -- Auto Generated Identity column
        ,'', '')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [menu_code] OFF
```

I would recommend to do this all the time anyway - if you omit the list of columns (both on `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements), you're setting yourself up for nasty surprises down the road. Yes, it's a tad more typing - once, when you create the query - but it'll save you countless hours of headaches and trying to find nasty bugs...... just **define** the list of columns you want to work with **explicitly**, all the time.

**Update:** if you're inserting those values from another table, I would **HIGHLY** recommend using explicit lists of column names in both the `INSERT` as well as the `SELECT`:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [menu_code] ON

INSERT INTO [dbo].[menu_code] (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, IdentityCol, Col6, Col7)
   SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, IdentityCol, Col6, Col7
   FROM DM_LUBRICANTS.dbo.menu_code 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [menu_code] OFF
```

Comment: but i am direcly inserting like this
set identity_insert menu_code On
insert  into DM.dbo.menu_code select * from DM_LUBRICANTS.dbo.menu_code

Comment: but i am direcly inserting like this set identity_insert menu_code On insert into DM.dbo.menu_code select * from DM_LUBRICANTS.dbo.menu_code

Comment: @UsmanHussain: no **but** - you **MUST** explicitly define the list of column on your `INSERT` command. Just try it - it'll work! And for the `SELECT`, I would **also** recommend to use explicit column names instead of just `SELECT *` anyways......

Comment: dear i can't provide the whole list of all columns because i my aplication i have to insert the values in all the table from one datadase to the table of another database i just make loop on all columns and insert all the data from one database to another 
like this
insert  into DM.dbo.menu_code select * from DM_LUBRICANTS.dbo.menu_code 
above query is working under the looop where the data of all tables is to be inserted to another table

Comment: dear is it posible without providing the list of all columns

Comment: @UsmanHussain: well, if you want to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ... ON` then you **MUST** provide the explicit list of columns. Otherwise, **IT WILL NOT WORK**.